# ASP.NET/IIS application using Windows Authentication keeps giving login pop-up

Tags: asp.net, popup, windows-authentication

They can usually get to the home page (which has the same security as the rest of the pages), then at some point, they are challenged for their login.  Some users are challenged right away and never get into the home page.

But not for all users, and for those users with problems, they say they *wait a day*, and they can log-in again.  What the heck!?

Looking at the event log, it just says `URL authorization failed for the request.`  If it consistently happened for a user, I could easily debug this, but it comes and goes!

I am using ASP.Net 2.0 Authorization (Roles & Users) and Windows integrated authentication.  The users are running IE6 mostly, some are IE8, but both versions experience the problem.  IIS is configured for NTLM.  Using Fiddler, it looks like the browser asks for NEGOTIATE then settles on NTLM.  I am at my wits end.  Any ideas where I should look.

**Windows Application Event:**

```
Event Type:        Information
Event Source:    ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0
Event Category:                Web Event 
Event ID:              1314
Date:                     7/5/2011
Time:                     2:55:06 PM
User:                     N/A
Computer:          {server}
Description:
Event code: 4007 
Event message: URL authorization failed for the request. 
Event time: 7/5/2011 2:55:06 PM 
Event time (UTC): 7/5/2011 9:55:06 PM 
Event ID: e634bad1af3845619cf6eecffd2caa84 
Event sequence: 40 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/Root/QER-1-129543759860957088 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: /QER 
    Application Path: E:\QER\ 
    Machine name: {server}

Process information: 
    Process ID: 8492 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://{server}/QER/reports/QuarterlyReport.aspx?position=14190&fiscal_year=2&quarter=1 
    Request path: /QER/reports/QuarterlyReport.aspx 
    User host address: 142.52.48.43 
    User: {DOMAIN}/{user}
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: Negotiate 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
```

Comment: Is this running SSL by any chance?

Comment: It's running on plain vanilla HTTP--no SSL.